# Display Json Values using webapi

Tags: c#

I have datatable for fetching my datas from mysql table and i using a foreach loop for getting each value.So i want to convert each value to json and need to display all these values.How can i possible?

My Table

```
public static DataTable GetAlldata()
{
    try
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;database=mytable;uid=myid;";
        string query = "SELECT Tname FROM `mytable`.`tdetails`";
        MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        ma.Fill(DS);
        return DS.Tables[0];

    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}





public string jsonvalues()
{
    string s = "";
    RootObject ro = new RootObject();
    DataTable dtaltheat = GetAlldata();
    foreach (DataRow drow in dtaltheat.Rows)
    {
        string theatnme = drow["TheatreName"].ToString();
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        s = ser.Serialize(theatnme);
        List<string> List = new List<string>();
        List.Add(s);
    }
     return s;
}
```

This is the present status of my code.But it doesn't work..I am new in this field,so help me..

Comment: What exactly you mean by "doesn't work" ? Where it's failing? What's the error message etc.

Comment: @ArghyaC:actually i don't have any better idea to implement this.So that's why the error happened

Comment: When you return an object from a WebApi action it is automatically converted to josn or xml, depending on what the request says it wants.

Comment: @hakkeem With the information you have provided in question, it's gard to help you! Couple of points [1] This line `ser.Serialize(theatnme)` is trying to serialize a string, which will *most probably* not help you in any way. [2] Please update your question with these info a. What error you got, with error message and details b. some sample of finally what you want to return from your `jsonvalues()`